# Sections of the canonical bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

This is maybe a stupid question.

Let $M$ be a simply-connected complex (kahler?) manifold, is it true that the canonical bundle $K_M$ has always (global) sections?

For example, we know that an Enriques surface is not simply-connected, but its canonical bundle has no sections. On the other hand, a K3 surface is simply-connected and its canonical has sections.

I was wondering if this is always the case. My guess is: yes! but I still cannot prove it. If anyone can give me an hint it will be much appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: For every simply connected complex manifold with $c_1(K_X)<0$, $K_X$ has no global section: If it does, then the divisor $D$ cut out by the section will be effective and $c_1(D) \ge 0$.

Comment: Dear @John, thank you again. Actually I was wrong, but what happens for general $c_1(M)$? I mean, what if $M$ is simply-connected but, for example, $c_1(M)=0$ or $c_1(M)>0$?

Comment: Do you know the canonical bundle of projective space?

Comment: Dear @Relapsarian, thank you. This is the last evidence that I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the several interesting results about existence of global holomorphic section on P. Griffiths and J. Harris, Principles of algebraic geometry, Wiley, New York (1978).

If $L$ is a holomorphic line bundle over a compact Kahler manifold $M$ such that $c_1(L) < 0$,
then there are no nonzero global holomorphic sections of $L$. For proof see this [survey paper](http://math.columbia.edu/~faulk/FirstChernClass.pdf)

Let $L$ be a holomorphic line bundle over a compact, Kahler manifold $M$ with $c_1(L) = 0.$
If $L$ is not the trivial bundle, then $H^0(M, L) = 0.$ See [Proposition 10.4](http://math.columbia.edu/~faulk/FirstChernClass.pdf)

Reid conjecture: If $X$ is a $\mathbb Q$-Fano 3-fold, then $\mathcal O_X(-K_X)$ has a global section.

[Lemma 16.3](https://books.google.fr/books?id=eII1drlOBMkC&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=%22global%20section%22%20KX&source=bl&ots=leAlDUqZWC&sig=oNiuUF_Nh5K3qHy4RzUsl6PMRTQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif9v3noJvYAhWHD8AKHU9ADPYQ6AEIMjAD#v=onepage&q=%22global%20section%22%20KX&f=false): Let $X_d$ in $\mathbb P(a_0,...,a_4)$ be a family of $\mathbb Q$-Fano 3-folds with only isolated terminal singularities. Suppose also that $a_0\leq a_1\leq ...\leq a_4$ and $a_4\nmid d$, then $\omega_X^{-1}$, has a global section.

The space of global sections of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P_k^n}(d)$ is $0$ for $d < 0$ and isomorphic to the vector
space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in $n + 1$ variables for $d ≥ 0$. [See p.13](http://www.math.ens.fr/~debarre/M2.pdf)